# xcode: Missing argument label 'at:' in call

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm quite new with swift.

Who is pressed into the app to delete the photo and the comment to be deleted.

I get the message at:

self.comments.remove(post["message"] as! String)
self.imageFile.remove(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

Missing argument label 'at:' in call

The delete function:

```
   @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

        if let posts = object {
            for post in posts{
                print(posts)

                let objectIdVar = post["objectId"] as! String
                post.remove(forKey: "objectIdVar")
                self.comments.remove(post["message"] as! String)
                self.imageFile.remove(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong and how I can do right's me?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Unrelated but do not reload the table view in each iteration of the loop. That's unnecessary expensive. And better use `tableView.deleteRows` to get an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `remove` method on arrays that takes the thing you want to remove as a parameter, you can only remove the element at a certain index:

```
self.comments.remove(at: self.comments.index(of: post["message"] as! String)!)
```

If you want such a `remove` function, consider using a `Set` instead, or write your own extension:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func remove(element: Element) -> Element? {
        guard let i = self.index(of: element) else { return nil }
        return self.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is difficult than I thought. How do I properly implemented this?

Comment: You use the extension in the second code snippet, or use a `Set`, which has the `remove` method you want. @Daniel.P

Comment: i have, self.comments.remove(post["message"] as! String)
                    self.imageFile.remove(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile) by self.comments.remove(at: self.comments.index(of: post["message"] as! String)!)
                    self.imageFile.remove(at: self.imageFile.index(of: post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)!) replaced. I get the message to Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @Daniel.P then either the dictionary's values do not match the types you specified, or the element does not exist in the array.

Comment: He knows not of which cell contents to be deleted. I think. each cell is a photo and a comment. Who is in the cell on delete clicks to delete the contents of the cell, or better the entire cell contents. I have the first question added a screenshot. I'm probably wrong addressed that

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the signature of the `remove(at:)` function [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641390-remove) :

```
@discardableResult mutating func remove(at index: Int) -> Array.Element
```

All you have to do is add 'at:' in your call like so:

```
self.comments.remove(at: /*Have an Int here*/)
self.imageFile.remove(at: /*Have an Int here*/)
```

Make sure that comments and imageFile are mutable arrays for `remove(at:)` to work.